# angular 2 - checkbox "checked" depend on function not on property biind

Tags: checkbox, angular, checked, angular2-forms

I have a checkbox that needs to be shown as selected depending on a function result instead of binding it to an object property.

This would be easy, but is not possible:

```
<input type="checkbox" ([ngModel])="category.selected">
```

And this does not work, as even `checked="false"` results in a checkbox being displshownayed as selected:

```
<input type="checkbox" [attr.checked]="isCategorySelected(category.id)"/>
```

I need an outcome like this

```
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

depending on the result `isCategorySelected(id)`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try returning `null` instead of false.. that should work with `[attr.checked]`

Comment: This works. Thank you!

Comment: Your solution worked for me @Sasxa. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `[(ngModel)]` in this scenario because it defines a 2-way databind, and you are passing a function.

Instead, you could simple use `[ngModel]`, like the snippet below. This syntax defines a one-way databind.

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="yourBooleanFunction()"/>
```

You can read more about `ngModel` [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel).

Let me know if you have any other problem with it.

Comment: but this function is being called infinite times.